# Redis sort by score and date

Tags: sql, node.js, database, redis, nosql

I'm trying to strategies how to calculate position/rank based on score and date

I have a two pieces of data with the same score shown in the image below.

If i run the command

`$ZADD usersScores 11 userId6`

It will add it above **userId5** which is not something I want

Is it possible to add it below userId1 maybe based on date?

[image]

**This is my goal essentially  where i would like to show the position based on the amount and the oldest would be ontop via date**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Sorted Set ordering

Sorted sets are ordered by their scores first, and then lexigraphically by their members if the scores are equivalent. So in your case if you added the following keys:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 11 user1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 11 user5
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 24 user3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 54 user2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 11 user6
(integer) 1
```

and then did a ZRANGE, you'd get them in ascending order with the members ordered in alphabetical order:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange myset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
 1) "user1"
 2) "11"
 3) "user5"
 4) "11"
 5) "user6"
 6) "11"
 7) "user3"
 8) "24"
 9) "user2"
10) "54"
```

What it looks like, is your GUI is using, or are just passing in the rev argument to ZRANGE under the hood, which orders everything in reverse (scores descending, reverse alphabetical)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myset 0 -1 WITHSCORES REV
 1) "user2"
 2) "54"
 3) "user3"
 4) "24"
 5) "user6"
 6) "11"
 7) "user5"
 8) "11"
 9) "user1"
10) "11"
```

### Second sort-by

There are a couple of ways you could handle the second sort by with a sorted set, let's assume you wanted to do this with a 32 bit unix timestamp

1. You could prepend the second sortby field to the member name so if user6's score came in at `1659579650`, you'd just make the member name be `1659579650:user1`, then when it orders it, it would do so lexigraphically
2. You could combine the score with the second, since 11 is the score, we could shift 11 32 bits to the left and add/or the timestamp to it, which comes out to `48,904,219,906`, those will then order correctly, and then when you want to find the score, all you need to do is right-shift the score by 32 bits.

Comment: Sorry if I don’t see the answer. Is it possible to do 

 "user2"
=>
 "user3"
=>
 "user1"
=>
  "user5"
=>
 "user6" 


And 1 5 and 6 both have the same score of 11? @slorello I modifed the question a bit if it helps!

Comment: No, the issue is that user6, user5, user1 are all in reverse lexigraphical order (you are ordering in reverse above), so that's why. You could potentially use [RediSearch's](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/) [aggregations](https://redis.io/commands/ft.aggregate/) to allow you to sort by multiple fields in a hash or json object (this would require a different storage pattern though.)

Comment: You could do user1 > user5 > user6 > user3 > user2 given the data above, that would be in the standard order of a sorted set

Comment: understood last question! if you dont mind is it possible to get one piece of data in reserve order for example user1 => user2 => user=> . Is it possible to get user1? @slorello

Comment: You can access individual members by their rank within the sorted set using ZRANGE, in your case here, you can access user1 by accessing it as the first element in a regularly sorted ZRANGE (`ZRANGE myset 0 0`) or you can access user1 by accessing them as the last element of the reversed sorted set (`ZRANGE myset -1 -1 REV`). You can check the rank with `ZRANK` and `ZREVRANK`